# putting headers into an array, python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a set of data that is below some metadata. I'm looking to put the headers into a numpy array to be used later. However the first header needs to be ignored as that is the x data header, then the other columns are the y headers. How do i read this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood what you mean by headers (it would be easier to tell with a few complete lines, even if you had to scale it down from your actual file)...

I would first read the irregular lines with normal python then, on the regular lines, use genfromtxt with skip_header and usecols (make a tuple like (i for i in range(2,102))